# PHP unset sessions and cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm new at programming and I'm working with some PHP. I was given a file called `login.php` and some directions to create a second file called `admin.php`.

---

Here are the instructions.

> `admin.php`
>
> - If the user tries to access this file without logging in, re-direct them back to the login.php page which should display a message saying “Invalid Login” – use the session variable to check.
> - If they are logged in:
>
>   - provide them with the value of the “loggedIn” cookie with the message: “You logged in January 25, 10:00am” (or whatever the value is)
>   - unset the session variable and destroy the session and
>   - unset both cookies (session and ‘loggedIn’) and set to expire so it will be removed by the browser.
>   - NOTE: test the already logged in portion of login.php before adding the code to destroy the session and the cookie.
>
> Once you’ve got the above working, change your code so that if they are redirected to login.php from admin.php, it should display a different message: “You need to log in”.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $message = null;

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 'true') {
        header("Location: admin.php");
        exit();
    }

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
        if ( sizeof($_GET) && isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']) && $_GET['username'] && $_GET['password']) {
            if ($_GET['username'] == 'username' && $_GET['password'] == 'password') {
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 'true';
                setcookie ("loggedIn", date("F d,Y h:ia"),  time()+60*10, "/", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
                header("Location: admin.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                $message = 'Invalid Login';
            }
        } else {
            $message = 'Invalid Login';
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($message) echo '<div class="warning">' . $message .       '</div>'; ?>
        <form method="get">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="username" />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  value="password" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

The code below is all I have so far. I want to know if my unsetting is correct with the session variables and cookies. Also, how do I display the date and time as stated in the instructions, and  how do I display a message of "You need to log in if the user is directed to the login.php page from the admin.php page?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 'false') {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        unset($_COOKIE['loggedIn']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I under stand what you are asking for completely. Let me know if it's not right.

First for message, I would do it by having it redirect to a GET URL
so maybe http://example.com/login.php?login=error or something like that.

So then you would say

```
if($_GET['login'] == 'error') {
    echo '<h1>You Need to login</h1>';
}
```

Now for the date and time I would look at [w3 school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp) so you can find the formatting you would like. If you still can't figure it out let me know.

And lastly for unsetting cookies, you should set the cookie equal to nothing. So setcookie("username", "")

Answer (score 0):

You are using a mixture of SESSION variables and COOKIE variables that seem to perform similar tasks.  You should have everything in SESSION variables, then when you want to log the user out you just need to call `session_destory`.

Also you are using `$_GET` variables to log in which can cause security problems as the variables will be visible in the URL, this means that anyone looking at that persons computer history will be able to see their password in plaintext in the URL.  You should switch to using `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake there:

```
!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == 'false'
```

is always eveluated to `false`:

```
$array = [];

$a1 = !isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] == 'false';

$array = ['loggedIn' => 'false'];

$a2 = !isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] == 'false';

$array = ['loggedIn' => 'true'];

$a3 = !isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] == 'false';

var_dump([$a1, $a2, $a3]);

// array(3) {
//   [0]=>
//   bool(false)
//   [1]=>
//   bool(false)
//   [2]=>
//   bool(false)
// }
```

Better use this:

```
!(isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] != 'false')
```

Results:

```
$array = [];

$a1 = !(isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] != 'false');

$array = ['loggedIn' => 'false'];

$a2 = !(isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] != 'false');

$array = ['loggedIn' => 'true'];

$a3 = !(isset($array['loggedIn']) && @$array['loggedIn'] != 'false');

var_dump([$a1, $a2, $a3]);

// array(3) {
//   [0]=>
//   bool(true)
//   [1]=>
//   bool(true)
//   [2]=>
//   bool(false)
// }
```

Comment: ...or `(@$rray['loggedIn'] ?: 'false') == 'false'` or another dosen of variants...